# CMake как подключить "headers-библиотеку"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, cmake, c++17

***Задача следующая:*** есть "статическая"-библиотека, на самом же деле это автоматически сгенерированная папка С/С++ хедеров. Проблема в том, что они не связанные между собою СМаке-ом, как того требует проект.

СМаке 3.23.3 / С++17 / Linux 18.04 / GCC 7.5.0

```
|- main.cpp
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- Libraries(subdir)
|      |- Mavlink(subsubdir)
|      |      |- *subdirs with headers and headers*
|      |      |- mav_main.h    // Main file to include in code
|      |- CMakeLists.txt(in_subdir)
```

Вот то малое, что как минимум не выбрасывало ошибок до недавнего времени:

CMakeLists.txt(main)

```
...
add_subdirectory(Libraries)

taget_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} Libraries/Mavlink)
...
```

CMakeLists.txt(in_subdir)

```
add_library(MAV INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(NAME_proj PUBLIC &{CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Спонтанно появилось следующие сообщение:

> .. cannot find -lLibraries/Mavlink

***Вопрос:***

1. Какие есть варианты решения задачи? Я встречал советы прописывания всего ручками, но там слишком много файлов.
2. Как автоматизировать (1) если иного выхода нету?
3. Возможно ли описать/ин-ть всю либу Mavlink из CMakeLists.txt(in_subdir)? В дальнейшем хотелось бы из нее управлять будущими либамию.

Comment: @AlexF,  add_library() частый случай в примерах, даже не с библиотеками. Касательно простого добавления: Суть в другом. Нельзя в каждую папку добавлять СМакеLists, важно управлять "библиотеками" из ../Libraries/СМакеLists. В противном случае, невозможно менять версии и тп.

Comment: `file(GLOB ...)`?